# DLink switch loses configuration on power off!

Tags: switch, troubleshooting, management, interface, hardware

We just bought a DGS-1210-28P smart switch, it is my first experience with a business class switch, however I found a pretty weird behavior. The switch loses all of its configurations, even management ip address and password, when it is disconnected from power! a complete factory reset happens!

Is this normal?! Am I missing something?

Does business switches board has batteries that I should check?

Comment: Are you saving the configuration?  If so, then you have a hardware problem.

Comment: of course I do save them, and the switch works with the configuration applied for as long as it is connected to a power supply.

Comment: Did using the CLI work for you? I have 2 identical units for the version prior to your's (DGS-1210-24) - one works fine and one won't retain the settings.

Comment: For me it turned that I have to go to some hidden menu item to invoke a process of saving the configurations, this is not the regular saving button available on every screen, this is a special save that used to save all of the switch settings to be reloaded back after restart.

Comment: It most likely relies on an EEPROM to save config. You’ve got a bad chip. Try newer - or current - firmware flash. If the problem persists, replace the chip or switch. These EEPROM chips are often removable, and are tagged.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this behavior with D-Link's in the past, it is hit and miss with their switches. If I saved from the web GUI, it wouldn't actually save, but saving using the CLI seemed to have always worked. Try it and let us know.

Comment: I will try it when I get back to work. Does the switch boards has batteries that I should check?

Comment: The DGS-1210-28P does not come with a battery

Comment: @guest_dlink_not_working But it comes with a delicious EEPROM.

Answer (score 3):

This has just happened to me with my Dlink DGS 3120-24SI.
Apparently you need to go to the web gui then select Save ... Save Configuration / Log.
Change Type to All, then Apply.

This saves everything into Non Volatile RAM to keep settings after power outs.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer given by patch67:
go to web gui, Save Configuration / Log. Change Type to All, then Apply.
works perfectly for my device: dgs-3120-48tc

Answer (score -1):

You can use on the CLI: save all